# Kubernetes Deployments and Jobs

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to run a single job which should wait for MySql deployment to start. And then there are several deployments where all deployments will wait for that single job to complete.

Comment: Rename the question to:  How to deploy an application on kubernetes only when another pod is up?

Answer (score 3):

The better thing for this use case is to use initcontainer in your others deployment that would check the MySQL pod to be up and running instead of a job - this is the best practice in kubernetes for this kind of thing ( you should add readiness probe in your MySQL deployment too )

Here is how to do this: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/#init-containers-in-use

Answer (score 0):

You can right small bash script in Job to check the status of MySQL deployment as soon as it comes **Ready** Job should move ahead.

it would be more easy with **HELM Hooks** to resolve your issue.

You just need to add annotation to helm template : https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: job
metadata:
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install
```

Helm will further release the deployment if the job gets **successful** or **complete**.

Read more : https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/

**Extra** :

If you are running CI/CD and executing a series of commands using just kubectl you can also checkout wait : https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#wait

`kubectl wait` will check for the condition to be met and print message acrrodingly.